# Простая графика в терминале c++

Tags: c++, графика, терминал

Как реализовать 20 графических кружков в терминале ?10 зеленого цвета и 10 красного.Все это под линуксом

Comment: В терминале? Кружочков? Ну, нарисуйте букву `o` 20 раз.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки ncurses.

Comment: В bash `printf "\x1b[31m\xE2\x97\x8F\x1b[0m\n"` выводит красный кружок (и опять переключает цвет в default)

Answer (score 2):

Символ кружка не входит в таблицу ASCII, так что его вывести нельзя.

Что касается цветов, стандарт C++ не поддерживает работу с цветами в консоли, решение вашей задачи зависит от конкретной операционной системы. Под Windows можно воспользоваться функцией [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), а под *nix можно использоваться [цветовыми кодами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

Comment: Многие эмуляторы терминала позволяют выводить не только ASCII, но и другие символы, закодированные в UTF-8. Например, "кружку" (юникод U+25CF) соответствует вот такая строковая константа в С/C++ `"\xE2\x97\x8F"`.

Comment: @avp да, но это зависит от конкретного терминала (терминал Windows, скажем, UTF-8 по-умолчанию не поддерживает). Но в любом случае, автор не указал целевую систему, поэтому дать какой-то конкретный совет очень сложно.

Comment: Это верно (пусть уходит из винды)